# When is right time to run Automigrate with GORM

Tags: go, grails-orm

Most Go/GORM examples I've seen show Automigrate being called immediately after opening the database connection, including GORM documentation [here](https://gorm.io/docs/). For API services, this would be an expensive/wanted call with every API requests. So, I assume, for API services, Automigrate should be removed from regular flow and handled separately. Is my understanding correct?

From [GORM Documentation](https://gorm.io/docs/)

```
...
db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("test.db"), &gorm.Config{})
if err != nil {
  panic("failed to connect database")
}

// Migrate the schema
db.AutoMigrate(&Product{})
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It wouldn't happen on every API request. Not even close. It'd happen every time the application is started, so basically: connect to the DB in `main`, and run `AutoMigrate` there. Pass the connection as a dependency to your handlers/service packages/wherever you need them. The HTTP handler can just access it there.

Basically this:

```
package main

func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("test.db"), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to connect to DB: %v", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    // see below how this is handled
    fRepo := foo.New(db) // all repos here
    fRepo.Migrate() // this handles migrations
    // create request handlers
    fHandler := handlers.NewFoo(fRepo) // migrations have already been handled
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/foo/list", fHandler.List) // set up handlers
    // start server etc...
}
```

Have the code that interacts with the DB in some package like this:

```
package foo

// The DB connection interface as you use it
type Connection interface {
    Create()
    Find()
    AutoMigrate(any)
}

type Foo struct {
    db Connection
}

func New(db Connection) *Foo {
    return &Foo{
        db: db,
    }
}

func (f *Foo) Migrate() {
    f.db.AutoMigrate(&Stuff{}) // all types this repo deals with go here
}

func (f *Foo) GetAll() ([]Stuff, error) {
    ret := []Stuff{}
    res := f.db.Find(&ret)
    return ret, res.Error
}
```

Then have your handlers structured in a sensible way, and provide them with the repository (aka foo package stuff):

```
package handlers

type FooRepo interface {
    GetAll() ([]Stuff, error)
}

type FooHandler struct {
    repo FooRepo
}

func NewFoo(repo FooRepo) *FooHandler {
    return &FooHandler{
        repo: repo,
    }
}

func (f *FooHandler) List(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    all, err := f.repo.GetAll()
    if err != nil {
        res.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        io.WriteString(w, err.Error())
        return
    }
    // write response as needed
}
```

Whenever you deploy an updated version of your application, the `main` function will call `AutoMigrate`, and the application will handle requests without constantly re-connecting to the DB or attempting to handle migrations time and time again.

I don't know why you'd think that your application would have to run through the setup for each request, especially given that your main function (or some function you call from `main`) explicitly creates an HTTP server, and listens on a specific port for requests. The DB connection and subsequent migrations should be handled before you start listening for requests. It's not part of handling requests, ever...

Comment: Thank you very much. I overlooked the fact that main function gets executed only when the application is started and not when the API calls are made. Appreciate your detailed answer.